# Cheerio получить html, включая корневой элемент

Tags: node.js, cheerio

Модуль [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)

Пример:

```
let $ = cheerio.load('<div id="test"><p>1</p><p>2</p></div>');
console.log($('#test').html());
```

Код вернет

```
<p>1</p><p>2</p>
```

А как вернуть вместе с `<div id="test">`?

```
<div id="test"><p>1</p><p>2</p></div>
```

Решение:

```
let block = $('#test');
return $.html(block);
```

вернет `<div id="test"><p>1</p><p>2</p></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение - https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/16

```
let $ = cheerio.load('<div id="test"><p>1</p><p>2</p></div>');
let block = $('#test');
return $.html(block);
```

вернет `<div id="test"><p>1</p><p>2</p></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Ничего лучше помещения клона в div не придумывается.

```
console.log($("<div>").html($('#test').clone()).html());
```

Когда-то видел похожий способ в AngularJS в случае, если `outerHTML` не поддерживается.

Comment: как вариант, да, но странно все это)

Comment: Все же нашел, - $.html($('#test')) - вернет все что необходимо.

Comment: @Bookin, опубликуй это отдельным ответом и прими его через 2 дня.

Comment: Добавьте в свой, я приму

Comment: @Bookin, ну это ж ты нашёл :)

Comment: не важно, главное будет ответ, что бы другие могли найти, плюс два варианта.

Comment: @Bookin, мне кажется два ответа лучше. Они всё-таки сильно разные.

Comment: хорошо, главное не забыть отметить теперь)